# is there any way to integrate Alert rules with Azuredevops WorkItems-bugs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-log-analytics, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-monitor

Looking for some way to create the ADO workitem type-bugs, whenever any created Azure alert rules trigger alerts.

Is there any inbuilt mechanisam available either in ADO or Azure loganalytic workspaces, where we created the alert rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any built-in way to do it.

You could create an [Azure Logic App that creates a task in DevOps](https://stefanstranger.github.io/2020/06/05/UsingAzureLogicAppToCreateBugWorkItem/) and then make it an Action for your Alert.

Connecting the ticket state back to alert state (i.e. to mark the alert as resolved once the bug is fixed) should be possible, but a lot trickier.

Comment: The document says about azure devops pipeline failed items to workitem. Is there any step by step guidance to enable it from Azure alerts to create Azuredevops Bug-Workitem ?